# Get cost value of a point in local costmap

Tags: ros, 2dcostmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone, I want to get cost value of a specific point in local costmap.
For example, i have a point and the position of this point is taken relative to map tf frame.  Can you tell me how to check cost value of the point in local costmap of robot ?

Thank you and happy new year !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/393619/get-cost-value-of-a-point-in-local-costmap/) by [N.N.Huy](https://answers.ros.org/users/52680/n.n.huy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 32 on 2022-01-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [N.N.Huy](https://answers.ros.org/users/52680/n.n.huy/) on 2022-01-04**:
Nice, thank you @Mike Scheutzow and @Osilva for your explanations. So I understand as the following steps:

1. I have to subscribe the `/move_base/local_costmap/costmap`
2. Then I have to transform the frame
   of the input coordination to the
   frame of costmap right ? Because my
   input is a coordination of map tf
   frame, but in the local costmap, I
   think it uses robot fame or something else, i am not sure.
3. Then I can use `getCost()` function as @osilva said.

So is the procedure I said above right ? And how can I do the transformation ?
Can I use [worldtomap](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/jade-devel/costmap_2d/include/costmap_2d/costmap_2d.h#L143) to do the transformation?

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2022-01-04**:
Take a look at the `nav_msgs/OccupancyGrid` message. It has all the info you need to calculate an index into the cell grid. (0,0) is the lower left corner of the grid. Since each cell value is an `int8`, cost probably scaled down to range 0-100 - you should verify that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`move_base` should be publishing the latest values on a topic named `/move_base/local_costmap/costmap`. Your ros node should subscribe to this topic.

I would not use `costmap_2d` class to monitor this data.  It is mainly used to create a costmap and apply sensor updates to that costmap.

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2022-01-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @N.N.Huy you could access the cost from a specific cell using `getCost()` function:

```
unsigned char costmap_2d::Costmap2D::getCost (unsigned int mx, unsigned int my )    const
```

Get the cost of a cell in the costmap:

**Parameters**:

**mx**: The x coordinate of the cell

**my**: The y coordinate of the cell

Returns: The cost of the cell

http://docs.ros.org/en/indigo/api/costmap_2d/html/classcostmap__2d_1_1Costmap2D.html#a061e2f97719abf41bc7c0426dad1c573

---

Originally posted by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) with karma: 1650 on 2022-01-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Paulidrobo](https://answers.ros.org/users/84392/paulidrobo/) on 2023-02-02**:
It is not working like this.
The value is always displaying 0.
I think what @Mike mention might be true.
Will try that.

**Comment by [mduz10](https://answers.ros.org/users/93156/mduz10/) on 2023-03-01**:
Hey Paul,
I've tried to take costs with costmap_2d::Costmap2D::getCost but I couldn't. Which way is true to take the cost value of costmap?